# Debugging in the stock browser on a Samsung Galaxy S4 on KitKat

Tags: android, browser, android-4.4-kitkat, samsung-touchwiz

We have a Javascript bug that only appears in the stock browser of the Galaxy S4 (GT-I9505) running KitKat (4.4.2) and we're unable to debug it or view the Javascript console. I've tried running `about:debug` and it does enable the debug menu, but it also redirects me to a 'page not found' and going back/forwards removes the debug menu.

We've also tried using `logcat`, but no messages are shown (this command works perfectly on a Nexus 4 JellyBean and in an emulated Gingerbread).

`adb logcat browser:V WebCore:V Console:V *:S`

We've also tried [JSConsole](http://www.jsconsole.com) and [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) but nothing useful is shown on their console. We also implemented the 'DIY Console' as suggested by [EclipseSource](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/08/14/debugging-javascript-on-android-and-ios/) and while it did show an error, it doesn't tell us which file the error comes from or any specific details.

Does anybody have any other suggestions for things to try, or a solution as to why `about:debug` isn't behaving properly?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work for you, but I have a Galaxy S4 and I was able to see console messages this way:

1. Plug in your phone, make sure you're getting all the logcat messages
2. Add this filter: `INFO:CONSOLE`
3. Javascript errors are printed under the chromium tag and the "Info" log level